# Excel Java - Pass a Row of Cell Values to an ArraList

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, collections, apache-poi

I'm wondering how to store the entire row's cell values into ArrayList

Ex.
Table_Alphabet

Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4

Alpha| Beta | Gamma| Delta

mono | poly | tera | exa

So, here I'd like to take the 1st row {Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta} and store the whole row into the ArrayList.

I've tried to use the ArrayList for this cell values(using Apache POI!)

```
ArrayList<String> level1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then store that ArrayList to the parent_ArrayList which can contain actual arrayList

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> parent_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

but I'm not getting through this.

```
for(int i=0;i<noOfRows;i++){

            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0; j<lastCell;j++){
                Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                 switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                         level1.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                         break;

                     case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                         cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                         level1.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                         break;
                 }                              


            parent_list.add(level1);
            }
 }
```

Please suggest me the proper approach to get past this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean you are not getting through this? I had a quick look on what we use, and your code is fairly similar to our.

Comment: @Flanfl Does this code look good to you?
Moreover, I just checked the childArrayList (level1)- It prints the values perfect. But how do I loop through parent_list(ArrayList of ArrayLists)?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<noOfRows;i++){
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int j=0; j<lastCell;j++){
            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
             switch (cell.getCellType()) {

                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     innerMembers.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                     sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");
                     break;

                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                     cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                     innerMembers.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                     sb.append(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");
                     break;
             }                              


        rowList.add(innerMembers);
        }
        level1.add(sb.toString());
        parent_list.add(level1);
}
```

since you need to store a `single row` in an `arraylist` seperated by `commas` you need to create a  `StringBuilder` and append cell values to it first once that is completed . add the `stringbuilder to arraylist` and then add the `arraylist to the parentarraylist`.try with above code this might help you.